# Need to change pathing in Terminal for installing future Homebrew installs

Tags: macos, path, homebrew

I believe I have the path for saving Homebrew installs set up wrong in Terminal.

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Returns: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Pretty sure I shouldn’t have /usr/local/bin:  TWICE

What do I need to enter in Terminal to correct this?

I am trying to get Mac to install future Homebrew installs in the correct folder. I am on new Mac with Yosemite.
The article I was following was this, at the section on pathing environment:
http://burnedpixel.com/blog/beginners-setup-guide-for-ruby-node-git-github-on-your-mac/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this PATH to an other file: `.zprofile` .

type `code ~/.zprofile` and add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This depends heavily on how you have your shell initialization set up.  If you followed that article to the letter, open `~/.bash_profile` and delete the line at the end that prepends `/usr/local/bin` to the path.

Having something twice in the path isn't really a disaster, however, so if you are not comfortable with doing this, just leave it there.